# NLog not Logging in Simple App

Tags: vb.net, nlog

I am trying to implement a simple log using Nlog 1.0, using the following code

```
  Dim _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
  _logger.Debug("Iain")
```

And the following NLog.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <targets>
      <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Site.log" layout="${date}: ${message}"/>
    <target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog" source="My App" log="Application" layout="${date}: ${message} ${stacktrace}"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="eventlog" />
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

The app just dosnt seem to be logging, any ideas?

Cheers

Iain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minLevel is not set to log Debug messages.

NLog levels are:

- Fatal
- Error
- Warn
- Info
- Debug
- Trace

When you have minLevel set to Info, it will only log Info and higher;  Debug and Trace messages will not be logged.

Comment: Did you set the minLevel to "Debug" or "Trace"?

Comment: Hmm... I have NLog 1.0 logging to both file and sql server.  By any chance, are you using this in a web app in the asp.net development server?  I have noticed that I need to shut down the asp.net dev server process to have it refresh settings, though I cannot remember specifically if that was for NLog.

Comment: I am running a windows forms application, bassically trying out Nlog, no real code apart from what i included/

Comment: Ok, I think I know what is happening.  The nlog config file has to be in the output directory.  Did you set the 'Copy to Output Directory' property to 'Copy Always'?