# Why isn't nlog logging to a file in my ASP.NET project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nlog

I have both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Web Developer Express 2012.

I tried NLOG in VS 2010 in a console application and everything worked right.

But when I try it in VS2012 with my asp.net application, It just does not.

I've already tried restarting my VS: [NLog is not logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118695/nlog-is-not-logging)
And double-checking the loggin level: [NLog not Logging in Simple App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919083/nlog-not-logging-in-simple-app)

But still not luck.

Comment: so.. do you use the same configuration for for your console and asp.net application? if so please show the config section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured it out.

I installed NLog in the business logic library which was the one where I wanted to log. But I didnt install it in the main project (the asp one) so I just installed there, adjust the configuration and that solved it.